# Appending Timestamp with the filename

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(dataTable_leads,{
            'sSwfPath': '//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf',

            aButtons: [
                       { sExtends: "csv",
                         sFileName:  'GlData_' + updateTime() + '.csv',
                         sButtonText: "<i class='fa fa-file-text'></i>",
                         mColumns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

                       },
                       { sExtends: "xls",
                         sFileName: 'GlData_' + updateTime() + '.xls',
                         sButtonText: "<i class='fa fa-file-excel-o'></i>",
                         mColumns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

                       },
                       { sExtends: "pdf",
                         sFileName: 'GlData_' + updateTime() + '.pdf',
                         sButtonText: "<i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o'></i>",
                         mColumns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
                       }   
                   ] 
        });



function updateTime()
       {
        var currentDate = new Date()
        var day = currentDate.getDate()
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
        var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;


        var hours = currentDate.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getHours() : currentDate.getHours();
        var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getMinutes() : currentDate.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getSeconds() : currentDate.getSeconds();


        var t= hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;


        var x = d  + " " + t;

        return x;

    }
```

I want to add a timestamp with the filename saving. Here updatetime is working fine and its appending with the filename. But after 5 min also Time is keeping constant, Its not getting changed. System time will change but here it wont change. When you refresh the page then only while saving timestamp time is getting changed. How to resolve this issue? Please help me out

Comment: your timestamp have spaces before and in between. and could cause a href like this:  `GlData_10-12-2015 00 00 00.pdf`

Comment: That is not the issue. Already i have removed the space and tried. Its not working

Comment: you can use `setInterval()` then.

Comment: How to use here. Please guide me

Comment: Can anyone please help me here?